# Linear regression with XTS object

Tags: r, xts, linear-regression

How to do linear regressions with `xts` object?
`lm(xtsObject ~ index(xtsObject))` doesn't work, I've tried.

My data is a daily stock price of a company. but `index` gives the seconds since the epoch to `lm` function. How to solve?

Comment: The dyn package can perform regression on zoo objects.

Answer (score 4):

Extract the data from `xtsObject` and the time index (as you already do) into a data frame, giving each a suitable name. Refer to the variables in the formula using this name and pass as argument data this data frame. For example, using the example data in `?xts`:

```
require("xts")
data(sample_matrix)
xtsObject <- as.xts(sample_matrix, descr="my new xts object")

## the example ts has several variables Open High Low Close,
## here I take just one, "Open"
df <- data.frame(xtsObject['/'][,"Open"], Time = index(xtsObject))
head(df)

> head(df)
               Open       Time
2007-01-02 50.03978 2007-01-02
2007-01-03 50.23050 2007-01-03
2007-01-04 50.42096 2007-01-04
2007-01-05 50.37347 2007-01-05
2007-01-06 50.24433 2007-01-06
2007-01-07 50.13211 2007-01-07
```

Now fit the model

```
mod <- lm(Open ~ Time, data = df)
summary(mod)

> mod <- lm(Open ~ Time, data = df)
> summary(mod)

Call:
lm(formula = Open ~ Time, data = df)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.16144 -0.47952 -0.08462  0.57053  1.44329 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  3.199e+02  1.199e+01   26.68   <2e-16 ***
Time        -2.302e-07  1.020e-08  -22.57   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.6146 on 178 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.741, Adjusted R-squared:  0.7395 
F-statistic: 509.2 on 1 and 178 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

`lm()` knows nothing about **xts** objects so if in doubt, do the simple thing and passing it something it does know about.

Note you can do `coredata(xtsObject)` instead of `xtsObject['/']`, e.g.

```
> head(coredata(xtsObject))
         Open     High      Low    Close
[1,] 50.03978 50.11778 49.95041 50.11778
[2,] 50.23050 50.42188 50.23050 50.39767
[3,] 50.42096 50.42096 50.26414 50.33236
[4,] 50.37347 50.37347 50.22103 50.33459
[5,] 50.24433 50.24433 50.11121 50.18112
[6,] 50.13211 50.21561 49.99185 49.99185
```

Comment: I believe you've proposed a misleading but not all together incorrect solution.  Read my answer below and let me know what you think.

Comment: This isn't a statistical help site but a site about programming - the OP posed a question with *no* data. I made up some data and showed how to do what they wanted. It's up to the OP to decide what scale they want for the trend component - the only problem I can see with what I actually showed (not that I'd do this for my own data) is that the estimated effect for the trend is tiny given the large scale of trend variable. I can think of many reasons why having the trend start at 0 is not useful - an alternative would be to centre the time variable.

Comment: I respectively disagree.  If you are aware that the time trend starts at 1167724800 your approach is fine.  However, the results from this approach are not very readable. This is why in practice people select time trends which start 1 or 0 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_trend_estimation).  For example, if the time trend starts at one then the intercept represents the mean of the data.  For this reason I suggest that people consider the approaches I've outlined below.  Additional, using `dynlm` or `dyn` makes more sense than transforming to a `data.frame` to use `lm`.

Comment: The intercept represents the expectation of `y` when `x` is zero. If `x` starts at 1, the intercept relates to a point outside the range of the covariate, just as it does in my example. The time trend doesn't start at the ridiculous value you say it does: `as.numeric(as.Date("2007-01-02"))` gives `13515` - i.e. that many days since the epoch. I think you've mistaken the Dates for POSIXt times. Your approach could be just as misleading: `trend(x)` produces `seq_along(x)` for a regular time ordering - almost all the time series modelling I do is irregular in time.

Comment: My point here is that as the OP gives no data I made up some simple data to show how to extract exactly the time points of the data. I wasn't advocating that you use these *exact* dates - if I do this I often scale the time variable say by / 1000, or centre it so the intercept is well constrained inside the observations - I was just showing the process. Your approach makes assumptions too. I can see the utility of using something like **dynlm**, but only if the data are regular observations. Again, this isn't a site about statistical niceties - I've assumed the OP has a brain & will use it.

Answer (score 1):

The Gavin Simpson's solution is dangerous.  To see this, notice that when you run the regression above the time trend is `as.numeric(df$Time)`.  This time trend starts at 1167724800.  Generally time trends start at 0.  This is important, because if you are not aware of the origin of your time trend you will interpret your coefficient estimates incorrectly.  I have suggested several better alternatives below.

```
data(sample_matrix)
xtsObject <- as.xts(sample_matrix, descr="my new xts object")

#Option 1, the best by far, no need to transform to a data.frame
library(dynlm)
dynlm(Open ~ trend(Open), data = xtsObject)

#Option 2, another option
library(dynlm) 
xtsObject$t <- 0:(nrow(xtsObject)-1)
dynlm(Open ~ t, data = xtsObject)

#Option 3, the data.frame route
df <- data.frame(xtsObject['/'][,"Open"], t = 1:nrow(xtsObject))
lm(Open ~ t, df)
```

Comment: My answer is *not* dangerous. This isn't a site for statistical advice. I showed one way to use R to get what the OP wanted. Your point about not "being aware of the aware of the origin..." is a straw man argument. One would hope that if one were fitting a regression with data one would know how their data were formatted/coded and act accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

```
# Load library
library(tsbox)

# Convert xts to dataframe
dataframe = ts_data.frame(xts)

# See dataframe header
head(dataframe)

# Run regression
fit = lm(value ~ time, dataframe)

# Find result
summary(fit)
```